# How to divide data frame in r in groups of equal number of records and split dat randomly & equally in two data frames

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have some data that contains about 30000 records. I want to divide the data into groups of 288 records. And then sort the data into test_data & train_data separate data frames where first 4 records are stored into train_data while 5th record into test_data, sequentially and randomly. Randomly in a way any day of the 5 days is saved into test_data & rest 4 goes into train_data.

How this can be achieved ?

*Sampel data:*

```
 #   timestamp               var1      var2
    --------------------------------------
 1   01-01-2019 18:00:00      1.2       21
 2   01-01-2019 18:05:00      2.3       32
 3   01-01-2019 18:10:00      3.4       43
 4   01-01-2019 18:15:00      4.5       54
 5   01-01-2019 18:20:00      5.6       65
 . 
 .
 .
3000  ..   -    ..   ..        ..        ..
```

*Sample Output:*

```
#in case of sequencial OR contiguous division  
train_data = (#1,#2,#3,#4 .... #1152,#1441,......,#2592,...) 
test_data = (€253,#254,.....,#1440,.....,#2593,....)

#in case of random division, any 288 contiguous records from bunch of 5 in to #test_data and 4x288 into train_data.
```

*Currently, I have this method of data splitting.*

```
   set.seed(100)

    train <- sample(nrow(dataset1), 0.7 * nrow(dataset1), replace = FALSE)
    TrainSet <- dataset1[train,]
    #scale (TrainSet, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
    ValidSet <- dataset1[-train,]
    #scale (ValidSet, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
    summary(TrainSet)
    summary(ValidSet)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "randomly and equally". You want to first split your dataframe into a set of smaller dataframes, each with 288 records, correct? Then you want to split each one into two sets, training and testing? Do you mind clarifying the question with an actual example of the desired output, as well as the code you tried?

Comment: @Aziz: Basically as I put in some sample data, my data is observations recorded each 5 minutes of the hour. So there are 288 observations per day. I want to distribute data 4 days for training and 1 day for test data. So by splitting data into 288 records, I think that can be achieved. Not splitting data into data frames of 288 records but using 288 records as a unit OR group representing 1 day. The sample output I add and my code for sampling data.

Comment: The 30,000 observations represent 104 or 105 days and you want a training set of about 84 days and a test set of 20-21 days? But the sample should be systematic unaligned meaning that in each group of 5 days, one goes to test and the other four to training?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to keep data from the same day together, but want to split your "days" into two groups, 80% for training and 20% for testing?

Comment: @Aziz: exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
# assume the number of rows is divisible by 288
num_days = nrow(dataset1)/288

# Each value (True or False) indicates whether the *day* is included or not 
training.days.mask = sample(rep(c(T,T,T,T,F), length.out=num_days))

# To index the actual values, repeat each mask 288 times
training.samples.mask = rep(training.days.mask, each=288)

# now use the mask to extract the data
training.samples = dataset1[training.samples.mask,]
testing.samples = dataset1[!training.samples.mask,]
```

The idea is to first perform `sample` on day indices (not samples). Then, repeat each mask 288 times to capture the sample of a full day.

Comment: This will be faster than my approach, but it will fail if you have any gaps in your observations (i.e. some days with less than 288 observations unless the missing observations are represented in the data frame as NAs).

Comment: @dcarlson: Yes, I assumed that the data is full, the number of samples per day is exactly 288, and that the number of days is divisible by 5 (to get 4:1 training-testing ratio). Your approach is definitely more robust :)

Comment: There are no missing observations. The fields with missing data are marked as NA

Comment: Its not working basically. It omits some 2000 days out of 9000 observations. But if if see the data, it contains contiguous days, not omitting 5th day.And test-data i.e. testing-sample is empty data frame.

Comment: @XCeptable There was a typo on the code. I've updated it to create a single mask (for training data) and just invert it to get the testing data. It is working now.

Comment: Its working in this way that now testing-sample is not empty but as I mentioned earlier, its not not omitting 5th day from training-sample. Has all days included in both sets, with almost 80% data in training and 20% in test set.

Comment: Did you want every fifth day to be in the testing set? Or random days? The code above will select randomly 80% of the days as training data, and the remaining 20% as test data.

Comment: I need both basically but to start with is 4 days in training and every 5th day in testing.

Comment: If you don't want randomized days, and want to have every 5th day in the testing set, just remove the `sample` function call from the code above. So, that line will be `training.days.mask = rep(c(T,T,T,T,F), length.out=num_days)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
dat$day <- as.Date(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")  # Add the day for each observation
days <- unique(dat$day)                    # Get the days since it is the sampling unit
groups <- seq(1, 105, by=5)                # Assuming 30240 observations, 105 days
daystest <- sample(5, length(groups), replace=TRUE) + groups
datetest <- days[daystest]                 # Days in the test set
Testing <- dat[dat$day %in% datetest,]         # Test data set
Training <- dat[!dat$day %in% datetest,]
```

`Testing` is a data file of the original data for testing and `Training` is a datafile of the original data for training. Since you did not include a reproducible sample of your data, I can't test it.

Comment: > Testing <- dat[dat$day %in% datetest,]         # Test data set

Error in dat[dat$day %in% datetest, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Not enough information. As I said, I cannot test without a reproducible example. I cannot debug without a reproducible example either. One way to get that error message is if `dat` is a vector and not a data frame. I called your data `dat`. Did you?

Comment: sorry for that. No, I didn't call my data dat. Rather I thought timestamp is what is coming from my data as this is thing we are using to divide data into days.